# Sequelize Inserts only in child table (Association: belongsTo)

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have 2 models: `Users` and `Doctors` where the `Doctors` model has a `belongsTo()` constraint on `Users`.

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Doctors = sequelize.define('Doctors', {
    specialization: { type: DataTypes.STRING }
  })

  Doctors.associate = function (models) {
    Doctors.belongsTo(models.Users)
  }

  return Doctors
}
```

The `foreign key` appears in my database and the `CREATE TABLE` is done correctly, however

```
const newDoctor = await Doctors.create({
  specialization: req.body.specialization,
  Users: {
    firstname: firstname,
    lastname: lastname,
    email: email,
    password: password
  }
}, { include: Users })
```

when a request is sent, **it adds** in the `Doctors` table but it **does not add** in the `Users` table.

To mention that all the relations are done in another file and it all works.

Any ideas on how to make this work?

**EDIT**: So to be clear, the Users table **IS NOT getting populated**, but the Doctors is.

Comment: last year i used sequelize and it was enough just to create those models and call that `sync()` method on startup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes, Sequelize needs that you specify an alias on the association.

`Doctors.belongsTo(models.Users, { as: 'Users' })`

And on the create, you also add the alias.

```
const newDoctor = await Doctors.create({
  specialization: req.body.specialization,
  Users: {
    firstname: firstname,
    lastname: lastname,
    email: email,
    password: password
  }
}, { include: { model: Users, as: 'Users'} }).
```

The name on the alias and the object must be the same.

Comment: It worked! Tried something like this before but it didn't work, guess I didn't put the same names. Thank you!